# Restructure summery.csv file in jmeter performance testing

Tags: csv, jmeter, report, performance-testing

I'm executing Jmeter performance test which contain two threads. One Thread group is for data creation and the other one for test. At the end summery.csv file gives both results. (test creation and Test results).

Is there a way I can have only the Test result (result in Test thread group) in the summery.csv file

I'm using jmeter 3.3

I have use Setup thread group and tear down thread group for data creation and data clean parts. And remove summery report from those threads.This didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the summary results listener inside the test thread group instead of test plan level. By doing this way you only get the result for the respective thread group.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) in order to remove the sample results you're not interested in from the results file.

Filter Results Tool can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/)

[image]

---

Also be aware that [according to JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.1.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-1-1-released-td5728320.html) (or whatever is the latest stable version which is available at [JMeter Downloads](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page on next available opportunity)